# A coluna '<nome da coluna>' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tsql

Olá!

No sistema há coleta de dados para algumas perguntas e as respostas são de 0-100.
Meu banco de dados tem as seguintes tabelas: Pessoa, Pergunta, Pessoa_Pergunta_Resposta.

Estou tentando obter um select onde retorne o Id da pergunta, a própria perguta e a média de resposta entre essa pergunta. Para fazer tal ação estou utilizando a seguinte query:

```
SELECT ppr.IdPergunta, p.Pergunta , AVG(ppr.Valor) as MediaPergunta FROM Pessoa_Pergunta_Resposta ppr, Perguntas p WHERE ppr.IdPergunta = p.Id GROUP BY ppr.IdPergunta
```

Porém da o erro intitulado. 
Sei que o p.Pergunta deve estar na função de agregação ou no group by, porém pelo que aprendi, não faria sentido coloca-lo. Teriam alguma luz?

Obrigado!

Comment: Troque sua cláusula `GROUP BY ppr.IdPergunta` para `GROUP BY ppr.IdPergunta, p.Pergunta`. Por qual motivo você acha que não deve coloca-lo na cláusula GROUP BY?

Comment: eu havia tentado isso, e tinha dado erro... Agora com a sua query funcionou, estava fazendo algo errado. Obrigado!